# Is shiny dependent on having Rstudio?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to develop an shiny app, it works on my PC and not on my office server. The IT person at my office said that it is because the shiny depends on having Rstudio which they cannot install.

Therefore, I uninstalled my Rsudio to test if it works without the Rstudio. It did work and now I am asking to make sure that shiny is not dependent on having Rstudio.

Also, I can't find the R dependency of the shiny also. Does it need to be >R.3.2.5?

edited:
To clarify, this is the simple example from the shiny tutorial. It looks like this in my PC (without having shiny). I don't know how to check if I have any shiny server installed?!!!

[image]

And this is how it looks like when I try the same code on our server (R version is R/3.2.2)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Shiny applications can run on any computer that has R installed along with `shiny` and it's dependencies. I run shiny applications from a Windows server with neither shiny server nor RStudio installed. But keep in mind that getting the application to rum and connecting to it once it is running are separate issues. I'm not sure which issue you are facing from your question.

Comment: @SymbolixAU how to check if I have shinyserver on my pc or not. I uninstalled the Rstudio, and do not remember setting any shinyserver for myself. And if that helps, how to create a shinyserver? I mean any documents you could refer me to?!! Thanks

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for the info, not sure what you mean when you say (running and connecting to it once it is running are separate issues). I don't intend to publish the app with others. It is intended to be running only in an R session on our server for easier interpretation of the results. I edited an example above to clarify what I see as a problem at my end. Greatly appreciate if you could give me some more info on this. Thanks,

Comment: @SymbolixAU is not correct: you _can_ use the shiny server but you don't have to. Just call `runApp()` which is a function in the shiny package.

Comment: A couple of good resources to read: [shiny articles](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/), [introduction to shiny server](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shiny-server.html)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - you're indeed correct; I wasn't trying to imply you *need* shinyserver. I was trying to say that R sorts that out for you when you run an app.

Comment: @newbie, ignore my comment about getting it to run vs. connecting. That clearly isn't the problem. I've not seen this particular problem before, unfortunately.